# Figuring percentage difference

Tags: excel, formula

In cell H6 I have 300,000
In cell G14 I have 206,813

I can't figure out how to write a formula in Excel to calculate the percentage difference.  I keep coming up with like 45%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably did (H6 / G14) * 100 while you should do G14 / (H6 / 100) or (G14 / H6) * 100, what ever notation you like :)

Comment: @NKCSS: I tried those but it comes up with 68%.  I know that is right figuring from 0 - 300,000, then the 206,813 is 68% of 300,000.  But I want the difference in a percentage.

Comment: Then you just do 100 - ((G14 / H6) * 100) :)

Comment: @NKCSS:  I'm not sure what I'm doing but it still comes up with 31%.  31% is almost 1/3, so that would be like 233,333 out of 300,000.  I have 206,813 out of 300,000.

Comment: 31 x 1% (3000) = 93000... ~207.000 + 93.000 = 300.000

Comment: Your math is a bit off; 1/3 of 300.000 = 100.000, not 66.667 ;) Go over my previous comment, the math is correct.

Comment: @NKCSS:  I'm talking about 1/3 of the difference would be like 233,333.  300,000 - 200,000 = 100,000 / 3 = 33,333 + 200,000 = 233,333.

Comment: 31% is the right answer. We say 300.000 = 100%, then 100.000 = 33%, 200.000 = 67%. The difference between Your values = 93.187, which adds up to 31%.

Comment: @NKCSS:  This is getting confusing :)  I'm figuring from 200,000 to 300,000 not 0 to 300,000.  So, I think from my first post above it would be like figuring the percentage diff. between 6,000 to 100,000 which is 6%.  I think that is tha answer I'm looking for.  So the percentage diff. between 206,000 and 300,000 would be 6%.

Comment: @Mike: Sure, but why do it like that? You asked for the difference between the two; that implies that the first number = 100%; when that's not the case, make sure to include it. That would mean your code becomes (G14 - 200.000) / 1000

Comment: @NKCSS:  I'm sorry, but I didn't know how to ask the question other than the way I did.  Before I asked it I did a lot of research on it and it waas getting me more confused.  You last post helped though.  It is what I was looking for.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for difference percentage as outlined by [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_change_and_difference)?

Then do

```
=ABS((H6-G14)*2/(H6+G14))
```

If you want it shown as a percentage, multiply by 100 (or even better, set the cell to a percentage).

Comment: Plugging in your formula I come up with 38%.

Comment: If you know the value you want the result to be, edit your post and include it and we'll be able to help you better.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't know what the answer should be.  That's why I'm trying to figure a formula to do it for me.

Comment: @Mike But you know that 45%, 38% and 68% are all incorrect? Unfortunately, if you don't know what you are trying to achieve, we can't help you.